# BPMN can the end event have more than one input flow?

Tags: diagram, bpmn, signavio

I'm building a BPMN Diagram in Signavio, on the end node I have 3 inputs. I can save it without any errors, and I can simulate it without any bottlenecks. Is it right or I am missing something?

Comment: You are not missing anything _in general_, because an end event can indeed have multiple incoming sequence flows (see BPMN spec chapter 10.4.3). However, whether you are missing anything _in particular_ with regards to your example is impossible to say without seeing your diagramme. It is a good idea to always add your diagramme and give an overview of your process for these types of questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, an end event is allowed to have multiple incoming sequence flows according to the [BPMN 2.0 spec](https://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/2.0/PDF) (chapter 10.4.3).
khalito already answered that perfectly in a comment, I just wanted to put it also here in place so that the question can get marked as "answered".